# Can `dlopen` be used to load and mmap a static ELF executable (not library)?

Tags: linux, linker, elf, mmap, dlopen

If file `anexe` is static compiled, no symbols, no exports, ELF, can `dlopen("anexe", RTLD_LAZY)` be used to map it into memory?

My goal isn't to be able to reference symbols -- there are no symbols.  Rather, my goal is to be able to call its functions given their addresses (which are fixed, not PIC), and to read its data given address.  I was planning on doing this all via `mmap`, but realized that `dlopen`, though not designed for thhis, might be able to do it all for me.

Can dlopen be used that way?

When I try it, I get `dlerror`: `cannot dynamically load executable` - is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If file anexe is static compiled, no symbols, no exports, ELF, can dlopen("anexe", RTLD_LAZY) be used to map it into memory?

No (but see below).

> My goal isn't to be able to reference symbols -- there are no symbols. Rather, my goal is to be able to call its functions given their addresses (which are fixed, not PIC), and to read its data given address.

Note that a non-PIE executable can *only* be loaded at the address it was linked at. You can find which address that is by examining its program headers (programmatically, or with `readelf -Wl`).

Once you know which address it should be loaded at (and assuming that address is not already occupied by your own executable), then you can perform a series of `mmap` calls to "load" that executable into memory, and after that you can call its functions and read its data.

One complication is that the executable's initializers will not have run (you didn't call its `_start`, nor would you want to), and so functions in it may not run correctly, may crash, etc.

For example, given this binary:

```
$ echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - -static -no-pie -o a.out
$ readelf -Wl a.out | egrep 'Type|LOAD'

  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000400000 0x0000000000400000 0x000518 0x000518 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x001000 0x0000000000401000 0x0000000000401000 0x07fd01 0x07fd01 R E 0x1000
  LOAD           0x081000 0x0000000000481000 0x0000000000481000 0x026660 0x026660 R   0x1000
  LOAD           0x0a7928 0x00000000004a8928 0x00000000004a8928 0x0059c8 0x007298 RW  0x1000
```

you would need to perform 4 `mmap` calls (one for each `LOAD` segment), with `MAP_FIXED`. The address, file offset, size and protection arguments for `mmap` are obvious.

The `mmap` arguments for the last segment may not be: you would need to round address and offset down to `Align`, and extend the size by `0x928` to account for that rounding.